# Can the Dominated Convergence Theorem be applied here?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, dirac-delta

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y) \frac{y}{\epsilon^2} \exp\left(-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2\epsilon}\right) \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y$$

here $f$ and $\nabla f$ are assumed to be continuous and bounded.

I've been trying for a bit with no luck.  I think I would want to use the dominated convergence theorem, but I can't seem to bound the integrand by an integrable function.

I also tried a few different change of variables, which weren't so insightful.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Idea.** The intuition behind this integral is that

$$ \delta_{\epsilon}(x) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\epsilon}} e^{-x^2/2\epsilon} $$

approximates the unit Dirac mass $\delta_0(x)$ as $\epsilon \downarrow 0$ by some suitable approximation to the identity argument. Thus writing the integral in terms of $\delta_x$, $\delta_y$ and performing integration by parts,

$$ -\iint f(x, y) \, \partial_y  \delta_{\epsilon}(x) \delta_{\epsilon}(y) \, dxdy = \iint (\partial_y  f(x, y)) \, \delta_{\epsilon}(x) \delta_{\epsilon}(y) \, dxdy. $$

Letting $\epsilon \downarrow 0$, we expect that the limit is $\partial_y f(0, 0)$.

---

**Solution.** Let $I_{\epsilon}$ denote the integral inside the limit. Since the integrand is integrable, we can interchange the order of integration. Then by the integration by parts,

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x, y) \frac{y}{\epsilon}e^{-y^2/2\epsilon} \, dy
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y) e^{-y^2/2\epsilon} \, dy. $$

So if we let $g = \partial f/\partial y$, then we can write

\begin{align*}
I_{\epsilon}
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x, y) \frac{1}{2\pi \epsilon}e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2\epsilon} \, dydx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(\sqrt{\epsilon}x, \sqrt{\epsilon}y) \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2} \, dydx
\end{align*}

where we applied  the substitution $(x, y) \mapsto \sqrt{\epsilon}(x, y)$ in the second line. Since $g$ is bounded and continuous, by the dominated convergence theorem,

$$ \lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} I_{\epsilon} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(0, 0) \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2} \, dydx = g(0, 0) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0, 0). $$

Comment: Hi @SangchulLee, thanks so much for your answer.  The IBP helps "remove" one of the epsilons in the denominator, I am guessing.  But couldn't you have integrated by parts in the other variable to remove the second (and last) epsilon in the denominator, or, we can't do that, since we don't know that $f$ is twice-differentiable?  I basically want to know your intuition behind changing variables as a second move vs. IBP a second time.  Thanks so much,

Comment: @User001, Although the latter part of my solution is a technical shortcut, it is not an essential idea. We can equally establish the conclusion by standard *approximation-to-the-identity* argument without removing the 2nd $\epsilon$. What is important is that $\delta_{\epsilon}$ represents the Dirac unit mass as $\epsilon \downarrow 0$ in some sense. (Mass concentrates near $x = 0$ as $\epsilon \downarrow 0$.) Since the behavior of the Dirac mass is quite predictable, it is often helpful to manipulate the integral to the form $\int g(x) \delta_{\epsilon}(x) \, dx $ for some $g$.

Comment: Ok got it - thanks so much for your help, @sangchullee - have a great holiday :-)